# Connecting prometheus-alertmanager with zoom via an incoming-webhook

Tags: zooming, webhooks, prometheus-alertmanager

Hello I'm trying to start sending alerts to Zoom using prometheus-alertmanager's webhooks, but I keep getting error

```
msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=1 err="cancelling notify retry for \"webhook\" due to unrecoverable error: unexpected status code 401
```

Here is my config

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 30m
route:
  receiver: 'zoom'
  routes:
    - match:
        severity: warning
      continue: true
      receiver: zoom
  group_by: ['resource']
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 3h
receivers:
- name: 'zoom'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'https://inbots.zoom.us/incoming/hook/<SECRET>/'
    http_config:
      bearer_token: '<SECRET>'
```

has anyone tried using Alertmanager with ZOOM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Alert manager is formatting the Authentication header in a way different than the one Zoom is expecting. So the solution is to run a middleware between them. Simple proxy, which changes the Headers format should work if you don't care how the messages look in Zooms chat, but if you care about formatting messages something more complicated will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http-adaptor:
https://github.com/Code2Life/http-adapter

and like this configuration for Alertmanager:

```
- name: 'zoom'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://localhost:8080/'
    max_alerts: 1
```

and this environment variables for http-adapter:

```
PORT=8080
ZOOM_WEBHOOK="https://integrations.zoom.us/chat/webhooks/incomingwebhook/xxx************"
ZOOM_TOKEN="***********"
PRELOAD_CONF="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Code2Life/nodess-apps/master/dist/zoom-alert-2.0.zip"
```

Here is a more complete document:
https://github.com/Code2Life/nodess-apps/tree/master/src/zoom-alert-2.0